# Azurepipeline CI is triggering for every pull request - i want only on merge

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
trigger:
- production

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
   XXX
  
- script: |
    XXX

- script: |
    XXX

- script: |
    XXX

- task: CopyFiles@2
    XXX

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    XXX
```

Comment: Is there a PR policy/trigger defined for this branch? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

Answer (score 1):

Add a trigger for master branch only. When a PR into master completes, a commit will be added to master and will trigger your yaml pipeline.

```
trigger:
- master
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers

Comment: I only want the build to trigger when I merge the PR, not when a user submits it. It's currently trigger on the PR not the merge.

Comment: yes, this will only trigger when a PR is merged into master. AKA any change that happens to the master branch, trigger the pipeline.
FYI you have 'production' as your trigger branch, is this your master branch?

Comment: @user1417561: This trigger would work perfectly fine if you also add a policy to master branch, you can simply add minimum number of reviewers to your master branch, that way nobody would be able to commit directly to master branch without a pull request and trigger would trigger the pipeline as soon as there is a merge to master